# How to apply pseudo classes like :hover to ng2 pseudo class :host

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I know we can apply class styles to our host component in CSS like this:

```
:host(.active) {
   ...
}
```

Is there any way to apply pseudo classes like :hover in a similar way?
:host(:hover) doesn't seem to work. Nor does :host:hover. I know I can apply classes for that using host listeners in JS but that's weird to do something like that in this case.

EDIT: I'm using Angular 2.2.0

**EDIT2: My problem was that I haven't set :host to display: block so it was impossible to hover over it.**

Comment: :host is featureless, so :host:hover isn't going to work. This is why you need to use the functional variant, as in :host(:hover) - which works in Chrome, but I haven't gotten it to work in any other browser.

Comment: which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: I have added in comments that I'm using 2.2.0. I have checked your Plunker with 2.2.0 and it seems to work fine. I guess there's something wrong with my app then, thanks for a great answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:host(:hover) { ... }` should work but whether is working or not depends on `@Component({ encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.??? })`.

You have three options for [`ViewEncapsulation`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation):

- `ViewEncapsulation.None` - your component styles will be merged into global styles
- `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` - styles are renamed and unique attributes are added to elements in order to prevent global styles clashes. This emulates the shadow DOM.
- `ViewEncapsulation.Native` - uses the shadow DOM. This needs to be supported by the browser.

Note that `:host(:hover)` is correct and should work with all cases. `:host:hover` will work with `None` and `Emulated` but is not a correct way to write it for `Native`. Therefore, in order to be compliant try using `:host(:hover)`.

Therefore, due to the lack of support (check [can i use](http://caniuse.com/shadowdom/embed)), ensure that `encapsulation` is set to `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`. This should be the default option.

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RmuVZYx9CVkdtrlqhBK9?p=preview):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hover me please</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    :host(:hover) {
      color: Cyan;
    }
  `],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class App {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

The generated HTML will look like:

```
  <my-app _nghost-c0="" ng-version="4.2.4">
    <div _ngcontent-c0="">
      <h2 _ngcontent-c0="">Hover me please</h2>
    </div>
  </my-app>
```

And the style like:

```
[_nghost-c0]:hover {
  color: Cyan;
}
```

Comment: :host:hover is not supported by *any* version of the Shadow DOM, because the spec doesn't allow it. I would not expect it to work *anywhere*, not even emulated mode. I'm positive this is just an Angular thing.

Comment: @BoltClock yes, sorry for that, I changed it. It works for `None` and `Emulated` though. At least on Angular 4.2.4. Good remark indeed, we should keep using `:host(:hover) { ... }` always

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me

```
:host{ display: block} 
:host:hover { background: yellow;}
 or
:host(:hover) { background: yellow;}
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? :host:hover isn't going to match anything. This is why the functional variant exists.

Comment: What are you testing in? That sounds like a broken implementation.

Comment: That on hover the host element will become yellow. If I miss something or I have misunderstood the question, let me know.

Comment: No, I'm asking what browser you're testing in. Having a working demo within your answer that others can look at would be better, too. (I'm starting to suspect that this may just be an Angular thing, in which case, it's a flagrant violation of the spec, as with all things Angular.)

Comment: I'm testing on Chrome example here https://plnkr.co/edit/vDcQpskcxr2s0MSPILog?p=preview